# How to check if an empty record is clicked in an Access subform?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003, subform

I have a subform embedded in a main form. I have the following code for the onClick event of one field in my subform.

```
Private Sub my_field_Click()
If Not Me!my_field.Value Is Null Then

    'my code here...

End If
End Sub
```

I want to update a text box with a click on the field, but I got an error when I click the field before the subform is not fully initiated (by setting the field's data source). So I wrote the above code to check if there is any value now in the field. However, I got the run-time error 424: Object required when running this code. Strangely, when I inspect the value of Me!my_field.Value in the debug window at run time, it does give NULL value.

Any idea what went wrong here? What else should I do to do this checking?

I am running this in Access 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `IsNull()` function in VBA code.

```vb
If Not IsNull(Me!my_field.Value) Then
```

Comment: thank you @HansUp, this works great! I must have missed up SQL with VBA